# Cannot find symbol JasperCompileManager.compileReport(), JasperFillManager.fillReport()?

Tags: java, javafx, jasper-reports, report

I want to create report with Jasper on `JavaFX`. I export data from `MySql` into the Jasper Report and everything work correct. I import library Jasper Reports 6.2.0 to my project library on `Netbeans 8.2`. When i want to create method (in my case `showReport()`) to open Jasper File when one button is clicked, it show me error cnnot find symbol on `compileReport()` method and fillReport()`method.

here is also the picture of code!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD3Ef.png)
?

code is here:

```java
public void showReport(){
    try{
        JasperReport jasperReport = new JasperCompileManager.compileReport(" C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\fxmlTest\\src\\fxmltest\\newReport.jasper");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint   = new JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,connection);      
        JRViewer viewer  = new JRViewer(jasperPrint);
        viewer.setOpaque(true);
        viewer.setVisible(true);

        this.add(viewer);
        this.setSize(900,500);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println( e.getMessage());
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JasperCompileManager.compileReport`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperCompileManager.html#compileReport-java.lang.String-) and [`JasperFillManager.fillReport`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReport-net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport-java.util.Map-java.sql.Connection-) are `static` methods.

The syntax you're using on the right hand sides of the assignments

```
new JasperCompileManager.compileReport(" C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\fxmlTest\\src\\fxmltest\\newReport.jasper")
new JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,connection)
```

tells the compiler to invoke the constructors of the `static` inner class `compileReport` in `JasperCompileManager` and `fillReport` in `JasperFillManager` respectively. (Or alternatively the constructors of the classes `fillReport` in the `JasperCompileManager` package and `fillReport` in the `JasperFillManager` package.) However those classes don't exist which is why you get the compile time error. You need to remove those `new` keywords:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(" C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\fxmlTest\\src\\fxmltest\\newReport.jasper");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,null,connection);
```